# Könnte man "der" oder "die" anstatt "das" benutzen in "Auf Deutsch heißt das Löffel".?

Tags: word-choice

Es erscheint mir seltsam, in einer Sprache mit Geschlechtern immer das Wort "das" als Demonstrativpronomen zu benutzen. Wäre es richtig, wenn man statt wie in den folgenden Beispielen

> Auf Deutsch heißt **das** Frosch.
>
> Auf Deutsch heißt **das** Löffel.
>
> Wie heißt **das** auf Deutsch?
>
> Auf Deutsch heißt **das** Socke.

für "that" sagen würde:

> Auf Deutsch heißt **der** Frosch.
>
> Auf Deutsch heißt **der** Löffel.
>
> Wie heißt **der** auf Deutsch?
>
> Auf Deutsch heißt **die** Socke.

Comment: Auf Deutsch heißt **es** *der Frosch*. Auf Deutsch heißt der Frosch "Fridolin".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die Antwort ist kurz: Es wäre falsch.

Und zwar wäre es sowohl falsch, wenn du Grammatik als etwas Normatives verstehst, als auch wenn du es als Deskription in der Realität auftretender Sprachhandlungen kompetenter Sprecher auffasst; will sagen: **So was würde nun wirklich *niemand* sagen.**

Man muss sich viel Mühe geben, um Situationen zu finden, in denen deine Beispielsätze auftreten könnten. Dein

> Wie heißt der auf Deutsch?

könnte vielleicht noch hier zu hören sein: Ein kleines Kind, das zweisprachig aufwächst, zeigt auf einen Hund und fragt: *Wie heißt der auf Deutsch?* In diesem Fall ist der Satz wenigstens 'technisch' richtig; auch wenn die Situation befremdlich ist, weil das Kind ja auf Deutsch fragt und offenbar immerhin schon weiß, dass **der** Hund männlich ist.[1] Somit liegt nahe, dass das Kind auch weiß, dass der Hund auf Deutsch Hund heißt.

Reparieren lassen sich deine Sätze, indem man ein *es* einfügt:

> Auf Deutsch hießt es "die Socke", im südlichen Dialekt auch "der Socken".

Damit sind wir aber wieder bei der Neutrum-Form (*Auf Deutsch heißt das Socke*), die dir ja nicht gefallen hat.

Wohlgeformt ist auch folgender Satz:

> Auf Deutsch heißt das "die Socke".

---

[1] Anders als etwa im Bulgarischen, wo ein Hund/der Hund sächlich ist: куче/кучето. Das bulgarisch-deutsch aufwachsende Kind würde also möglicherweise eher fragen: *Wie heißt das auf Deutsch?*

Comment: Das Beispiel wird deutlich weniger absurd, wenn man als Frage in Bezug auf den Hund "Wie heißt der auf (o.B.d.A.) Italienisch?" einsetzt.

Comment: Ich frage mich, wie die Geschlechts in demonstrativen Pronomen gelöscht wurden. Es scheint, je weiter aus Rom die lateinische Sprache verbreitet ist, desto einfacher wurde es. "estas son cucharas", "celles sont cuillères", und endlich die Deutschen und Engländer sind zu faul um Geschlecht oder Zahl zu verwenden. Das sind Löffeln.

Comment: Vielleicht ist es eine Eigenart speziell romanischer Sprachen? Die Bulgaren mit ihrer slawischen Sprache sagen: *Как се казва това?* - *Това е мишка.* - *Wie heißt das da?* - *Das* (n.) *ist eine Maus* (f.), nicht etwa *Тази е мишка*  - *Diese* (f.) *ist eine Maus* (f.) wie es - wie du sagst - möglicherweise die Postlateiner täten.

Comment: @user135711: Auch im Französischen gibt es geschlechtsneutrale vergleichbare Wörter, z.B. *ceci*. (Beachte übrigens, dass der Plural von *Löffel* im Nominativ *Löffel* lautet.)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper C'est ça, in Spanisch gibt es auch "esto".

Answer (score 2):

Das "das" in deinen Fällen ist eigentlich eine Verkürzung. Man könnte länger sagen:

> Wie heißt das Ding (dort) auf Deutsch?
>
> Auf Deutsch heißt das Ding (, das du meinst,) Frosch.

Ein Demonstrativpronomen wird, wie der Name schon sagt, verwendet, um auf etwas zu verweisen. Wenn das Geschlecht dieses angesprochenen Dinges allerdings mindestens einem Gesprächspartner noch nicht definitiv klar ist, benutzt man grundsätzlich ein "das", um Missverständnisse bzw. eventuell aus Unwissen entstehende grammatikalische Fehler zu reduzieren (ein "das" ist nie völlig falsch, da man wie oben notfalls einfach "das Ding" sagen kann - "der" oder "die" passen dagegen nicht immer). Das ist in der Regel der Fall, wenn man Wörter aus zwei verschiedenen Sprachen vergleicht - deren Geschlecht muss auch bei identischer Meinung nicht zwangsläufig übereinstimmen (vgl. die Sonne *f.* <=> le soleil *m.* und la lune *f.* <=> der Mond *m.*).

Wenn hingegen aus dem vorherigen Kontext **eindeutig** ist, welches Geschlecht gemeint ist, kann man durchaus auch die anderen beiden Geschlechter mit "heißen"  verwenden:

> Gestern kam der Film "Die Hard" im Fernsehen.
>
> Wie heißt **der** auf Deutsch?
>
> Auf Deutsch heißt **der** "Stirb Langsam".

Das funktioniert im Prinzip aber nur, wenn man ein konkretes Objekt (hier den Film) benennt. Bei so etwas abstraktem wie der allgemeinen Übersetzung eines Wortes hört sich alles andere außer "das" sehr merkwürdig an. Was wahrscheinlich auch daran liegt, dass die Konstruktion "das" + "heißen" schon teilweise idiomatisch ist und äquivalent zu "das" + "bedeuten" verwendet wird (im Gegensatz zur eigentlichen wörtlichen Bedeutung "das" + "benennen").