# Warum gibt es keinen bestimmten Artikel im Satz "Da ich mir unsicher bin, hatte ich folgende Überlegungen angestellt:"

Tags: word-choice

> Da ich mir unsicher bin, hatte ich folgende Überlegungen angestellt:

Dies ist [von dieser Seite](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4183/am-flughafen-oder-im-flughafen). Ich stolperte beim Versuch, eine unabhängige Frage zu beantworten.

Ist der Mangel an einem Artikel wegen des Adjektivs, der Pluralität oder des verwendeten Verbs begründet?

Zum Beispiel, wenn das Adjektiv stattdessen "weiter" wäre, wäre das für mich sinnvoll.

---

Auch ein anderes Beispiel [von diese Seite](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/36976/24132) habe ich, im Singular diesmal, gefunden.

> "Wohlgeformt ist auch folgender Satz:"

Gibt es Adjektive die keine bestimmten Artikel erfordern?

Comment: Bist Du Zeitreisender? "Da ich mir ... bin" ist Gegenwart, "hatte ich" Vergangenheit. Wie kann die Gegenwart Ursache für etwas Vergangenes sein?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es muss heißen:

> Da ich mir unsicher bin, hatte ich folge**nde** Überlegungen angestellt:

Da ist ein Doppelpunkt am Ende des Satzes. Die Überlegungen werden also direkt danach aufgezählt. Man kann einen bestimmten Artikel verwenden,

> Da ich mir unsicher bin, hatte ich die folgenden Überlegungen angestellt:

um noch zusätzlich mit dem Finger (demonstrativ) auf die folgende Liste zu zeigen, das ändert aber an der Bedeutung nichts.

Anders sieht es aus, wenn keine solche Liste folgt:

> Da es keine Birnen gab, habe ich Äpfel gekauft.
>
> Da es keine Birnen gab, habe ich die Äpfel gekauft.
>
> Da es keine Birnen gab, habe ich diese Äpfel gekauft.

Das sind drei Abstufungen: ohne jeden Fingerzeig, mit bestimmtem Artikel ("kleines Demonstrativprononomen"), mit echtem Demonstrativpronomen.

Comment: Muss es nicht "Da ich mir unsicher *war*" lauten? Oder "stelle ich folgende Überlegungen an".

Comment: Ich habe das Beispiel des Fragestellers möglichst unverändert übernommen. Ja, man könnte noch "war" oder alternativ "habe" einsetzen. Dieses Fass wollte ich nicht auch noch aufmachen.

Answer (score 2):

Zunächst einmal: Dein Beispiel enthält einen Fehler. Es muss heißen:

> Da ich mir unsicher bin, hatte ich <del>*folge*</del> **folgende** Überlegungen angestellt.

Ob am Ende ein Punkt oder ein Doppelpunkt steht, tut hier nichts zur Sache.

---

Im Deutschen gibt es bestimmte Artikel,

> der, die, das, des, dem, den

unbestimmte Artikel,

> ein, eine, eines, einer, einem, einen

und den sogenannten Null-Artikel

> 

Letztes ist eine Möglichkeit, das Fehlen eines Artikels auszudrücken. Wenn man annimmt, dass es diesen Null-Artikel gibt, wird vieles einfacher zu verstehen.

---

Bestimmte und unbestimmte Artikel verhalten sich unterschiedlich wenn man damit den Plural bildet:

- **bestimmt**
  Der Plural eines bestimmten Artikels ist selbst auch ein bestimmter Artikel:

  - singular

    > **Der Tisch,** der bei mir in der Küche steht, ist aus Glas und Metall.
  - Plural

    > **Die Tische,** die bei uns im Büro stehen, sind alle grau.
- **unbestimmt**
  Der Plural eines unbestimmten Artikels ist der Null-Artikel

  - singular

    > **Ein Tisch,** der drei Beine hat, kann nicht wackeln.
  - Plural

    > **Tische,** die in Möbelhäusern ausgestellt sind, sind immer sauber.

---

Der Null-Artikel kann aber noch mehr:

Wenn du deinen Beispielsatz im Singular formulierst, sieht er so aus:

> a) Da ich mir unsicher bin, hatte ich **eine** Überlegung angestellt.
>   b) Da ich mir unsicher bin, hatte ich **folgende** Überlegung angestellt.
>   c) Da ich mir unsicher bin, hatte ich **die folgende** Überlegung angestellt.

Das, was hier fett hervorgehoben wurde, sind [Determinative](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinativ_(Wortart)), das sind Wörter, deren Aufgabe es ist, das Nomen, das sie begleiten, genauer zu bestimmen, wobei *»genauer«* durchaus auch als äußerst vage verstanden werden kann. Unbestimmte Artikel vollbringen nämlich das Kunststück, das Nomen im Sinne eines Determinativs *genauer* zu bestimmen, und es gleichzeitig aber dennoch unbestimmt zu lassen.

Determinative sind Wörter, die aufgrund des Satzbaues vor einem Nomens stehen müssen, auch wenn von der Bedeutung her gar keine *genauere* Bestimmung notwendig ist.

Im folgenden Beispiel fehlt das Determinativ, was den Satz fehlerhaft macht, obwohl damit eigentlich dasselbe wie im Beispiel (a) ausgesagt werden soll:

> Da ich mir unsicher bin, hatte ich Überlegung angestellt. (Singular und fehlerhaft, weil ein Determinativ fehlt)

Artikel gehören zu den Determinativen, und der Null-Artikel, als Plural der unbestimmten Artikel, gehört ebenfalls dazu:

> Da ich mir unsicher bin, hatte ich Überlegungen angestellt. (Plural und korrekt, weil der Null-Artikel die Rolle des Determinativs übernimmt.)

Das Wort »Überlegungen« steht hier also ganz in Übereinstimmung mit allen Grammatikregeln ohne (echtes) Determinativ im Plural, weil der (gedachte und unsichtbare) Null-Artikel alles wieder zurechtrückt.

---

Ergänzung zum Null-Artikel:

Der Null-Artikel kommt auch in der Einzahl vor, dann aber als bestimmter Artikel. Er wird aber nur bei Eigennamen verwendet:

> Hier kommt Kurt. (Gemeint ist ein bestimmter Kurt. Vergleiche: »Hier kommt der Kurt.« »Hier kommt ein Kurt.«)
>   Berlin ist groß. (»Das Berlin ist groß.«)

Comment: Muss es nicht "Da ich mir unsicher war" lauten? Oder "stelle ich folgende Überlegungen an". Warum korrigierst Du nicht die Frage an der Stelle, wo sie einen Fehler hat, nach dem nicht gefragt wird?

Comment: @userunknown: Zur Nicht-Korrektur: Ich habe das nicht korrigiert, weil es sich zum einen um ein wörtliches Zitat handelt, und weil ich andererseits annahm, dass dieser Fehler mit ein Grund für die Verwirrung des Fragestellers war. Daher wollte ich den Umstand, dass hier ein Fehler vorliegt, explizit ansprechen.

Comment: @userunknown: Zu *bin/war*: Nein, nicht notwendigerweise. Ich kann über einen längeren Zeitraum hinweg, der von der fernen Vergangenheit bis in die Gegenwart reicht, unsicher sein, was man üblicherweise mit dem Präsens ausdrückt (*»Ich **bin** mir schon seit 1985 unsicher«*). Das Anstellen von Überlegungen erfolgt aber an einem Zeitpunkt, der in diesem Beispiel in der Vergangenheit lag. Daher kann (wenn der Kontext weitere Bedingungen erfüllt) das Plusquamperfekt durchaus die korrekte Wahl sein. Ich gebe aber zu, dass ohne Kontext die beiden Zeitformen nicht gut zueinander passen.