# Article with Independent Possessive Pronouns / Artikel mit Possessivpronomen als Nomenvertreter - 'Ist das deine?‘

Tags: colloquial, possessive-pronoun, demonstrative-pronoun

I have a question about using Independent Possessive Pronouns. Is it more normal to use 'das' with them regardless of the gender of the item, or should you use the correct definite article or pronoun? For example, I am in a waiting room, and someone is walking away leaving behind a pair of glasses (eine Brille). Which is better 'Ist das Ihre?' or 'Ist sie Ihre?'? Or at work and I locate a customer’s computer and I say ‘Ist das Ihrer?‘ or ‘Ist der Ihrer? What about plurals? Someone is looking for shoes: can I say ‘Ist das deine?’. I would really appreciate help.

Comment: Actually this is no possessive pronoun, see this [German question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/36974/1696).

Comment: Short answer: For me it would be correct to ask 'Ist das deiner / deine / deins?' talking of a 'Stift / Tasse / Buch'. In plural it's simple: 'Sind das deine?' But you might as well ask 'Ist der hier Ihrer? [= Mantel] / Ist die hier Ihre? [= Tasche] as 'Ist das hier Ihrer / Ihre / Ihrs?' 'Ist der Ihrer / die Ihre?' are at least extremely unusual, I think they're wrong. Talking of a person you are more likely to say 'Gehört der zu Ihnen?', which is slightly derogatory because of the 'der', you'd better say 'Gehört dieser Mann / Junge zu Ihnen?' Anyway you must know the gender to get it correct.